org-mode export HTML with translations
A variety of websites have a feature where you visit a webpage and if you append a language code (e.g: /fr /es /en, etc); the website will load that webpage's translation into the selected language.
Does org-mode publish / export support a feature like this?
Where you have to versions of the exact same file in two different languages and org mode manages the rest?
Thanks in advance

Can you provide an example of such a site? AFAIK, there are many ways of doing a multi-language site, but there is no standard way. You can do it as a collection of parallel static sites (which seems to be what you are talking about), but then most of the work is writing each file and all its translations. Organizing the files by language is the obvious way of doing it during development, but then the publishing is basically trivial: just copy the whole directory structure to another place: not sure what support you expect from org-publish. Caveat: I may not know what I'm talking about...

Thanks for the reply NickD. My question was a bit vague, I must admit. i was thinking if there were any org mode tools that would allow one to write a single org file; with all the translations inside it. Then; one would only have to have a single org file. I have found this github repo: https://github.com/mrlee23/org-multilingual/blob/master/org-multilingual.el. I'll look into it; it looks to be kind of what I was looking for
